# Grouping result according to one column in sql

Tags: sql

I have a sql statement like

```
SELECT column1, column2,column3, column4  FROM table1 GROUP BY column3
```

or

```
 SELECT *  FROM table1 GROUP BY column3
```

I want a result which is grouped according to column3 and also has other columns. But it gives an error.What should I do? thanks..

Comment: This makes no sense, hence your errors... add some sample data at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your expected end result correctly,
try using ORDER instead of GROUP

if however that does not give you your desired output, i apologize.

```
SELECT column1, column2,column3, column4
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY column3

SELECT *
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY column3
```

Comment: GROUP is used with aggregate/count functions. Its purpose basically is to calculate sum/average/count etc for different values in a column... eg if a column1 has values 1,2 and 3, although repetitively (not uniquely) and say column2 has other integral values... doing a SUM for eg on column2 will yield a single row answer
However a GROUP by column1 added to that statement will result in 3 rows, each containing SUM of values in colmn to corresponding to column1 values of 1, 2 and 3 respectively.
I hope i am being clear.

Comment: actually I had already tried this before I wrote this question and it didn't work. But when I append word "ASC" or "DESC" it works..

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is an undefined behavior. When you specify `GROUP BY` on a column, there can be multiple values in other columns. There is no sane way for the database to figure out what values to show.

`PARTITION` is probably what you are looking for. Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Grouping applies to aggregate functions such as SUM(). It doesn't make sense to group individual fields.

```
SELECT SUM(col1), MAX(col2), col3 from t1 group by col3
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood your question exactly and what for you need this query, but maybe you can use this one:

```
/*t-sql example*/

create table #T (id int identity(1,1), col1 varchar(5), col2 varchar(5), col3 varchar(6))

insert #T (col1,col2,col3) values ('aaa','a1e','group1')
insert #T (col1,col2,col3) values ('bbb','a2e','group1')
insert #T (col1,col2,col3) values ('ccc','a3e','group1')
insert #T (col1,col2,col3) values ('ddd','a4e','group2')
insert #T (col1,col2,col3) values ('eee','a5e','group2')
insert #T (col1,col2,col3) values ('fff','a6e','group3')


select id,col1,col2,#T.col3,subq.cnt from #T
join 
(select col3, COUNT(*) as 'cnt' from #T group by col3) as subq
on 
#T.col3 = subq.col3
```

I have used sub-query, but you can use temporary table or WITH. Also, I have used "count" for aggregation just for example.

Max